# Remover obrigatoriedade em input com anguljar

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Tenho uma dúvida com o angularjs, estou fazendo um formulário de cadastro, e tem um determinado formulário que estou fazendo uma validação e possui uma opção de inserir vários telefones, ele insere os telefones limpa os dados do input e vai pra uma lista com angular repeat.

Minha duvida é, quando eu inserir ao menos 1 telefone, ele vai remover a obrigatoriedade do campo (required), ou setar o campo como valido.

Tentei Usar o `$setValidity();` mas não foi também o que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Trecho do código que estou utilizando

```
var $formElem,$formScope;
$formElem = angular.element(formCliente);
$formScope = $formElem.scope();
$formScope.formCliente.telefone.$setValidity('required', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `ng-required` , que pega uma expressao e adiciona ou não o required de acordo com o resultado da sua variavel.

```
<input type="number" data-ng-model="telefoneInput" ng-required="temAlgumTelefoneNaLista"/>
```

sendo que sua `$scope.temAlgumTelefoneNaLista = (suaListaDeTelefones.length > 0);`

Comment: Pior que na estrutura do codigo que fiz, ele precisa de usar o atributo 'required' mesmo, pq é um validador automatico, eu passo o formulario, e ele me exibe em um popup os campos do formulario dividido em abas, os campos que sao obrigatórios e nao estao preenchidos

Comment: sim, mas voce voce vai passar a var atraves dessa 'propriedade' agora.. e nao mais pelo campo da model ligado ao seu input